# BITS job throws an error trying to download a zip file

Tags: http-headers, httphandler, microsoft-bits

We get this error from the BITS job when trying to download a zip file from a remote server (we implemented an HTTP Handler for zip files on that server):

ERROR CODE:    0x80200013 - The server does not support the necessary HTTP protocol. Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) requires that the server support the Range protocol header.
ERROR CONTEXT: 0x00000005 - The error occurred while the remote file was being processed.

My understanding is that the error suggests we should add the Content-Range header. I added the header, now the code looks like below:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; fileName={0}", downloadFileName));
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fs.Length.ToString());
fs.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);

context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.Close();
```

, but I keep receiving the same error.

I also tried the following line:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
```

but ended up with a different error: "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally".
The download link works perfectly fine in the browser.

i will appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates that your server does not meet the [HTTP Requirements for BITS Downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Bits/http-requirements-for-bits-downloads). Does the server accept HEAD requests?

BITS users should configure download jobs with [BITS_JOB_PROPERTY_DYNAMIC_CONTENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bits5_0/ne-bits5_0-__midl___midl_itf_bits5_0_0000_0000_0002) and [BG_JOB_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bits/ne-bits-__midl_ibackgroundcopyjob_0001) when targeting non-compliant servers. Bear in mind that this will result in BITS having to restart the download from scratch if/when it gets interrupted (e.g., due to connectivity issues or system reboot).

Comment: Yes, this is a reason why it did not work for me. After I rewrote a code to support the requirements, it started working. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Worked well.  In my case setting dynamic content was sufficient but foreground also worked. For easier reference the flags are here: /download /DYNAMIC  /priority FOREGROUND